# How to check for empty array inside a payload ?

Tags: mule, mule-component, dataweave, mule-esb

I am trying to have a choice condition where i will run a flow depending if array is empty.

Example :

```
Input : {"data":{"detailsSearch":[]}}
```

My code :

```
1. #[payload.data.detailsSearch*.size() > 0]
2. #[payload.data.detailsSearch*?]
```

I am getting an Runtime exception :

```
org.mule.api.MessagingException: Execution of the expression "payload.data.detailsSearch*.size() > 0" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException).
```

I am looking for snippet to check for empty and null for this array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Sandeep, you can try

```
#[dw('sizeOf payload.data.detailsSearch')>0]
```

Comment: Hi @Ralph Rimorin, This syntax is failing when I check payload after the database select because the database is returning '[ ]' if there are no records.

Answer (score 1):

In Mule 4 you can use Dataweave expressions in a choice router. If using Mule 4, you can use Dataweave 2.0 syntax and the `sizeOf` function:

```
<choice>
    <when expression="#[(sizeOf(payload.data.detailsSearch)) > 0]">
        ...     
    </when>
</choice>
```

Otherwise if you are using Mule 3, you can just use MEL and java syntax. Like so:

...

Comment: Thanks for the help Ryan! Could you please share the Mule 3 snippet as we are using 3.9

Answer (score -2):

Sandeep,

This MEL should work. Before this, to extract data like this you should convert json to java.util.HashMap object.

```
#[payload.data.detailsSearch == empty]
```